# Pattern for updating TabController length from child widget

Tags: flutter

The main page has many children widgets. When searching, `SearchWidget` is shown, otherwise `DashletsWidget` is shown.

`DashletsWidget` has `TabController`. `TabController` is kept in the main page, so that active tab is not reset after searching.

`DashletsWidget` has a dashlet setting pane, which might change number of tabs.

`DashletsWidget(ValueNotifier<int> dashletCount, TabController controller)` use `ValueNotifier` to let re-create `controller` to the parent: . While re-creating, the old TabController cannot be disposed reliably, so let just de-reference without disposing. It is kind-of-work, but so un-natural. Is there a good pattern to update `TabController.length`.

Answer (score 10):

It's fine to let your unused `TabController` be garbage collected.

Here's another strategy that might feel better: You could have store the information about the number of tabs in a model object that is owned in a `State` at a higher level of your tree than `DashletsWidget`, and pass that model object as configuration values to `DashletsWidget`. If the `DashletsWidget` is rebuilt and the constructor arguments change, the `didUpdateWidget` method of `DashletsWidgetState` will be called and you can use that as an opportunity to replace the `TabController`. Or alternatively you could use the number of tabs to construct a `ValueKey` for `DashletsWidget` and so changing tabs configuration would automatically `dispose` the existing `DashletsWidgetState` and replace it with a fresh one.

Comment: Thanks for GC tips and ValueKey trick. Moving state to parent will complicate things. DashletsWidget extends `StoreWatcher` which stores list of dashlet information. From what I tried, `StoreWatcher` is necessary to get instance of `Store`. The widget that extends  `StoreWatcher` are also not allow to use `TickerProviderStateMixin` for `TabController`. So it is deadend there. Current solution is also inadequate since there is some issue with Tab switching animation while swapping TabController.

Answer (score 8):

I found my own way of updating the `TabController`'s length.

I initialize it in `initState()` with a fake length, that works only like a placeholder. When I know the right length that the `TabController` should have, I initialize it again, but now with the right length. Here is what I mean:

```
TabController _tabController;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Initialize the TabController with a fake length
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 0);

    // Retrieve the number of tabs that will be displayed in TabBar
    _retrieveNumOfTabs().then((numOfTabs) {
      // Initialize the TabController with the right length
      _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: numOfTabs);

     // Add here all the controller's listeners
    });
  }
```

Comment: So this is not bad for performance and this not bad practice?

Comment: I suppose it isn't! What do you think about it?

Comment: I don't know either, I am going to use this method so that's why I was asking

Comment: In order to make this work, you can't extend from SingleTickerProviderStateMixin rather than from TickerProviderStateMixin. Other wise it will create an error saying you can't have two mixin

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:**

Since March/2019 this answer is no longer valid. A [pull request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/29332) have included a check and now the TabController's length must match the Tab count.

So it's definitely worth trying the [Salvatore's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56523528/796963), but if your tabs are really dynamic and may change a lot, in my opinion the only solution now is [Collin Jackson's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46183918/796963).

As Kyaw, I was struggling to adjust the `TabController.length` on demand, creating new TabControllers when the state changed (on setState, before building, on didUpdateWidget...). However, I'm not sure why that was not working.

What I'm doing (and it's working) is using the tab controller length as if it was "maximum length". So as the business logic of my app defines 20 tabs max, that's what I'm using as the length (20). I create the `TabController` with fixed length **once** at `initState()` and dispose it **once** at `dispose()`.

Despite of that, as long the `TabBar` and `TabBarView` have their tabs and children items correctly placed, for instance 2 items in both, their UI will work as expected for 2 items.

It's working with no glitches! (that I'm aware of) :)

Comment: Is there any side effects of defining large length? If length doesn't matter, then what's it for?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the answer.

Comment: If I initialize the `TabController` with a fake length instead of the real one (e.g. initialized with 20 but the `TabBar` will contain only 3 tabs), this exception is thrown: `Controller's length property (20) does not match the number of tab elements (3) present in TabBar's tabs property.`
How do you deal with this exception?

Comment: You are right, a [pull request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/29332) made 3 months ago included this check. I'll make a test and check if this check made it impossible to have a dynamic length TabController... The check itself is not wrong, let's see.

Answer (score 1):

With DefaultTabController:

```
  List<String> tabNames = ["a", "b", "C"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: tabNames.length,
        child: Scaffold(
          // add new tab on click
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () => setState(() {
                    tabNames.add("c");
                  })),
          appBar: AppBar(bottom: TabBar(tabs: tabNames.map((x) => Tab(text: x)).toList())),
          body: TabBarView(children: tabNames.map((x) => Container(child: Text(x))).toList()),
        ));
  }
```

If you are using slivers also add:

```
TabBar(controller: DefaultTabController.of(context), ...)
```

With TabController:

```
  List<String> tabNames = ["a", "b", "C"];
  TabController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TabController(vsync: this, length: tabNames.length);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // add new tab on click
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () => setState(() {
                tabNames.add("c");
                // might be good idea to dispose old tabController before
                _controller = TabController(vsync: this, length: tabNames.length);
              })),
      appBar: AppBar(bottom: TabBar(controller: _controller, tabs: tabNames.map((x) => Tab(text: x)).toList())),
      body: TabBarView(controller: _controller, children: tabNames.map((x) => Container(child: Text(x))).toList()),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this pattern for changing tabbar length with my items

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool inited = false;
  TabController? tabcontroller;
  final List<OrderTabbarWidget> tabbarWidgets = [];
  _initTabbarWidgets() async {
    setState(() {
      inited = false;
    });
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(
        milliseconds: 100)); //some time i give error if this method not exists
    final List<OrderTabbarWidget> _widgest = [];
    int getIndex() => _widgest.length;
    if (condition1)
      _widgest.add(OrderTabbarWidget(NewOrderAddressPage(), getIndex(),
          const Icon(Icons.location_on), OrderTabType.address));
    _widgest.add(OrderTabbarWidget(const NewOrderItemsView(), getIndex(),
        const Icon(Icons.category), OrderTabType.items));
    if (condition2)
      _widgest.add(OrderTabbarWidget(
          const SubmitOrderDiscountPage(),
          getIndex(),
          const Icon(CustomIcons.discount_tag_svgrepo_com),
          OrderTabType.discount));

    if (condition3)
      _widgest.add(OrderTabbarWidget(NewOrderDefaultShipping(), getIndex(),
          const Icon(Icons.local_shipping), OrderTabType.shipping));
    _widgest.add(OrderTabbarWidget(const NewOrderSubmitPage(), getIndex(),
        const Icon(Icons.checklist_rtl_outlined), OrderTabType.submit));
    _widgest.add(OrderTabbarWidget(const NewOrderPaymentPage(), getIndex(),
        const Icon(Icons.payment), OrderTabType.payment));

    tabbarWidgets
      ..clear()
      ..addAll(_widgest);
    tabcontroller?.dispose();
    tabcontroller = null;
    tabcontroller =
        new TabController(length: tabbarWidgets.length, vsync: this);
    setState(() {
      inited = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _resetMyTabbar();
    super.initState();
  }

  _resetMyTabbar() {
    /** fetch items or anything need for tabbar **/
    _initTabbarWidgets();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!inited) return const NormalProgress();
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _resetMyTabbar,
        child: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
            controller: tabcontroller,
            tabs: List.generate(
                tabbarWidgets.length, (index) => tabbarWidgets[index].tab)),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
          controller: tabcontroller,
          children: List.generate(
              tabbarWidgets.length, (index) => tabbarWidgets[index].widget)),
    );
  }
}
```

OrderTabbarWidget

```
class OrderTabbarWidget {
  final Widget widget;
  final int index;
  final Widget tab;
  final OrderTabType type;
  bool get isShipping => type == OrderTabType.shipping;
  OrderTabbarWidget(this.widget, this.index, this.tab, this.type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onTap` and `DefaultTabController` for changing local state, example

```
class Tab {
  const Tab({
    required this.title,
    required this.child,
  });

  final String title;
  final Widget child;
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({ super.key });

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyWidget> {
  List<Tab> _tabs = [];
  int currentTabIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: _tabs.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            onTap: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                currentTabIndex = index;
              });
            },
            tabs: _tabs.map((tab) {
              return Tab(
                text: tab.title,
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
        body: _tabs.map((tab) {
          return TabBarView(
            text: tab.child,
          );
        }).toList(),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
           setState(() {
             final text = 'Tab ${_tabs.length + 1}';
             _tabs.add(Tab(title: text, child: Text(text)));
           });
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```